# Can't download html page source

Tags: c#, webclient, web-scraping

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
          client.DownloadFile(new Uri(@"http://www.bilyoner.com/iddaa/iddaa-liste"),path);

        }
    }
```

I am trying to download the html source,but I am getting "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly." exception.
I tried different url s which just worked fine.

Comment: Maybe the server only allows standard browsers to access its content. Setting the user agent of a standard browser may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepting a zipped stream does the trick.

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.bilyoner.com/iddaa/iddaa-liste");
req.UserAgent = "MOZILLA/5.0 (WINDOWS NT 6.1; WOW64) APPLEWEBKIT/537.1 (KHTML, LIKE GECKO) CHROME/21.0.1180.75 SAFARI/537.1";
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");

GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(),
                                                      CompressionMode.Decompress);
var reader = new StreamReader(zip);
var page = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Are you saying that the server serves the file in compressed format and `WebClient().DownloadFile()` does NOT handle compressed format?

Answer (score -2):

Reference to the programming language used will be helpful here.
Are you sure that @ in

```
new Uri(@"http://www.bilyoner.com/iddaa/iddaa-liste")
```

is correct?
For debugging during development it is always useful to create references to ALL connections. I.e.

```
myConnection =  new Uri(@"http://www.bilyoner.com/iddaa/iddaa-liste");
client.DownloadFile(myConnection, path);
```

Comment: the @ just makes it a literal string ( your string can be multiline and you do not need to escape special characters anymores). But in this example, it is unnecessary. Not wrong, though :)

Comment: Thanks for down-vote. Though I suspect that using the code I offered would help the OP because it could fail on different line - if for example as suggested by "nunespascal" and "L.B" it may be a user agent or compression issue.

Comment: I didn't downvote. When I commented, you were at 0. I agree with using extra variables for debugging purposes. I do tend to remove those after I've confirmed the code is correct.

Comment: I know it is a matter of personal preference, I usually keep them because (from my point of view) they make the code more readable (and debugable) and it introduces no overhead - these objects are created anyway, just adding a local (properly scoped) reference in the code does not change anything.  (BTW: Thanks for down-vote was addressed at the person who down-voted, I did not mean you)

Comment: Hmm I see your point. It all depends on how well you need to maintain your code in the end. I tend to create libraries for later use, and then I do tend to clean up things like that as readability isn't preferred over slight performance gains. It's a minor performance gain, but if you chenge it a few 100 times, it becomes substantial.